# line 20:29 no viable alternative at character ' '

Tags: unit-test, class, failing-tests, method

Hi Salesforce stack exchange.

I am a newbie when it comes to apex, and struggling with a particular issues. 
I'm having created a simple test Utility Class (using examples online). The utility class should create two records: an account and a related child (Legal entity). Legal entity is a master detail relationship to the account. AML Process should now run from the "legal entity object". The test class "bg_AMLProcessExtension_Test" should reference the utility class "LegalEntityV1" and return the appropriate values.

I have added a picture of the fields that "insert aml" on bg_AMLProcessExtension_Test should be populating. (please ignore "Active Institutional Agreements" field 
 
[image: New Aml]

This is the utility class I have created

```
    public class LegalEntityV1{

    public static Account createOneAccount(){  
        Account testAccount = createAcct('ABC Computing inc.');     
        Legal_Entity__c testLegalEntity = createLE(testAccount); 
        return testAccount;        
    }

    // Helper methods //
    //   
    public static Account createAcct(string accountName) { 
        Account a = new Account(
            Name=accountName,
            Account_Type__c = 'Corporate',
            Account_Sub_Type__c = 'Family Office',
            Channel_Indicator__c = 'Institutional',
            RecordTypeid = '01258000000OnDB'
            );
              
        insert a;
        return a;
    }

    public static Legal_Entity__c createLE(Account a){
        Legal_Entity__c c = new Legal_Entity__c(
            Legal_Entity_Code__c = '1',
            Name = 'name',
            Organisation__c = a.ID); // *** Error is here ***
        insert c;
        return c; 
    } 
}
```

This is the "bg_AMLProcessExtension_Test" test class

```
 @isTest
public class bg_AMLProcessExtension_Test {


//DM Attempt 28/12/2016 
//Test data setup create 1 account with 1 Legal entity by calling utility method
public static testmethod void testSave()
{

Account testAccount = LegalEntityV1('Test');
testAccount.testLegalEntity = 'test';
update testAccount;


            AML_Process__c aml = new AML_Process__c(
            Client__c = testAccount.Id,
            Legal_Entity__c = testLegalEntity .Id,
            Client_Director__c = UserInfo.getUserId(), 
            Client_Executive__c = UserInfo.getUserId(), 
            Legal_Entity_Name__c = 'SIM UK',
            Stage__c = 'Checks In Progress', 
            Screening_1_Complete__c = Label.AML_Screening_1_Not_Complete, 
            Screening_2_Complete__c = Label.AML_Screening_2_Not_Complete
        );
        insert aml;
```

looking forward to your help

Comment: What line is 20 that is resulting in the "no viable alternative at character ' ''" error message?

Comment: You should really be working through Trailhead modules to gain a better understanding of Apex.

Answer (score 0):

In your test method, first create account and Legal Entity records and then you can access those account and Legal Entity data during `AML_Process__c` creation.

```
public static testmethod void testSave()
{
    Account testAccount = LegalEntityV1.createAcct('Test');
    Legal_Entity__c LEObj = LegalEntityV1.createLE (testAccount);
 //do rest of the process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me know if this works for you, I have added code modifying both the classes.
You need to create Account first and then assign that account Id to child record and insert the child record.

```
public class LegalEntityV1{

//Method to return Test Account
public static Account createOneAccount(){  
    Account testAccount = createAcct('ABC Computing inc.');         
    return testAccount;        
}

//Helper method to return Test Account
public static Account createAcct(string accountName) { 
    Account a = new Account(Name=accountName,
                            Account_Type__c = 'Corporate',
                            Account_Sub_Type__c = 'Family Office',
                            Channel_Indicator__c = 'Institutional',
                            RecordTypeid = '01258000000OnDB'
                            );
    return a;
}

//Method to return Legal Entity
public static Legal_Entity__c createLE(){
    Legal_Entity__c c = new Legal_Entity__c(Legal_Entity_Code__c = '1',
                                            Name = 'name');      
    return c; 
}}
```

2. Test Class

   ```
   @isTest
   public class bg_AMLProcessExtension_Test {

   //Method for testing
   public static testmethod void testSave(){
       //Create test Account Record
       Account objAccount = LegalEntityV1.createOneAccount();
       insert objAccount;

       //Create Test Legal Entity record
       Legal_Entity__c objLegalEntity = LegalEntityV1.createLE();
       objLegalEntity.Organisation__c = objAccount.ID;
       insert objLegalEntity;

       AML_Process__c aml = new AML_Process__c(Client__c = objAccount.Id,
                                               Legal_Entity__c = objLegalEntity .Id,
                                               Client_Director__c = UserInfo.getUserId(), 
                                               Client_Executive__c = UserInfo.getUserId(), 
                                               Legal_Entity_Name__c = 'SIM UK',
                                               Stage__c = 'Checks In Progress', 
                                               Screening_1_Complete__c = Label.AML_Screening_1_Not_Complete, 
                                               Screening_2_Complete__c = Label.AML_Screening_2_Not_Complete
                                               );
       insert aml;
   }//testSave
   }//bg_AMLProcessExtension_Test
   ```